# Elasticsearch search fo words having '#' character

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I am right now searching like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search?q=content:%23sachin
```

But, I am getting all the results with 'sachin' and not '#sachin'. Also, I am writing a regular expression for getting the count of terms. The facet looks like this:

```
"facets": {
  "content": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content",
        "size": 1000,
        "all_terms": false,
        "regex": "#sachin",
        "regex_flags": [
          "DOTALL",
          "CASE_INSENSITIVE"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

This is not returning any values. I think it has something to do with escaping the '#' inside the regular expression, but I am not sure how to do it. I have tried to escape it `\` and `\\`, but it did not work. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Not my area, but have you tried encoding the url as per the URL encoding standard (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)? This would give you http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search?q=content:%23sachin

Comment: yes..I have..infact it will error out without url encoding..I will update the url in the question.

Comment: What does your mapping look like? I think the '#' might not get indexed at all depending on your text analysis chain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article gives information on how save # and @ using custom analyzers:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014858/http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },  
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "tweet_filter" : {
                    "type" : "word_delimiter",
                    "type_table": ["# => ALPHA", "@ => ALPHA"]
                }   
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "tweet_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "tweet_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "tweet" : {
            "properties" : {
                "msg" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "analyzer" : "tweet_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This isn't dealing with facets, but the redefining of the type of those special characters in the analyzer could help.

Comment: thanks @andreatarr..I eventually got the same result when I searched and was implementing it. You can view a full discussion in the elasticsearch users group http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Elasticsearch-search-fo-words-having-character-td4037822.html

Comment: and for the facets part, once `#` results were coming correctly in the results, it was getting the count correctly. I think the facet was giving the count correctly earlier also, but when non # terms were also coming in the results, I was confused about the count.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that worth to consider is to index a special (e.g. "reserved") word instead of hash symbol. For example: HASHSYMBOLCHAR. Make sure that you will replace '#' chars in query as well.